# Multiplicative Inverse Element in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, inverse

So elements of this ring look like
$$a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{4}$$
If I want to find the multiplicative inverse element for the above general element, then I'm trying to find $x,y,z\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that 
$$(a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{4})(x+y\sqrt[3]{2}+z\sqrt[3]{4})=1$$
I can see that expanding gives me the system 
$$ax+2cy+2bz=1$$
$$bx+ay+2cz=0$$
$$cx+by+az=0$$
I don't want to solve this using matrices because I know it will turn ugly.  Is there a more elegant way to approach the inverse calculation to avoid the ugly calculation?  The only thing I thought of was setting the bottom two equations equal to each other
$$bx+ay+2cz=cx+by+az$$
Which seems to indicate that 
$$a=b, b=c, a=2c$$ but this would make me think $a=b=c=0$ and thus a multiplicative inverse does not exist.

Comment: "Which seems to indicate that ..." is of course wrong.

Comment: You could [represent your field by matrices](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125795/field-extensions-described-as-a-matrix)

Comment: I was sure that was not true, but a last minute effort before posting

Comment: Some posts that are related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294993/show-mathbbq-sqrt32-is-a-field-by-rationalizing and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533655/is-mathbbq%CE%B1-ab%CE%B1c%CE%B12-a-b-c-%E2%88%88-mathbbq-with-%CE%B1-sqrt32-a-fiel

Comment: @Martin Sleziak: duplicates, actually.

Comment: This post shows that denominator, which appears in the expressions given in the answers, is non-zero: I will just add that the denominator is non-zero: [Does $a^3 + 2b^3 + 4c^3 = 6abc$ have solutions in $\mathbb{Q}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422440/does-a3-2b3-4c3-6abc-have-solutions-in-mathbbq)

Comment: Of course no additional proof is necessary for this, since we know that $x \mapsto x \cdot y$ is invertible for abstract reasons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First let me remark that there is a general abstract argument which shows that if $L/K$ is a field extension and $a \in L$ is algebraic over $K$, then the $K$-algebra $K[a]$ is a field. Namely, $K[a]$ is an integral domain  which is also a finite-dimensional vector space over $K$. This implies for $0 \neq x \in K[a]$ that the linear map $K[a] \to K[a]$, $y \mapsto x \cdot y$ is surjective, since it is injective, which means that $x$ is invertible. To get a constructive proof, we just have to sit down and make the linear algebra argument here explicit.

The underlying vector space of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ has basis $1,\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{4}$. For some fixed non-zero element $x=a + b \sqrt[3]{2} + c \sqrt[3]{4}$, let's write down the linear map $y \mapsto x \cdot y$ in terms of this basis:

$~~~\,1 \mapsto a + b \sqrt[3]{2} + c \sqrt[3]{4}$

$\sqrt[3]{2} \mapsto 2c + a \sqrt[3]{2} + b \sqrt[3]{4} $

$\sqrt[3]{4} \mapsto 2b+2c\sqrt[3]{2} + a \sqrt[3]{4} $

The corresponding matrix is:

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & 2c & 2b \\ b & a & 2c \\ c & b & a \end{pmatrix}$$

From linear algebra we know how to invert matrices, for example via [Cramer's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Analytic_solution). In this case, we get:

$$\frac{1}{a^3 - 6abc + 2b^3 + 4c^3} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} a^2 - 2bc &  2b^2 - 2ac &  4c^2 - 2ab \\  2c^2 - ab &  a^2 - 2bc &  2b^2 - 2ac \\ b^2 - ac &  2c^2 - ab &  a^2 - 2bc \end{pmatrix}$$

The determinant $a^3 - 6abc + 2b^3 + 4c^3$ has been computed via the [Rule of Sarrus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus) and  the cofactors have been computed by the usual formula for $2 \times 2$-determinants.

This matrix represents the linear map $y \mapsto x^{-1} \cdot y$ with respect to our basis. Thus, to get $x^{-1}$, we just have to evaluate at $1$, and we get:

$$x^{-1} = \frac{1}{a^3 - 6abc + 2b^3 + 4c^3} \cdot ((a^2 - 2bc) + (2c^2 - ab) \sqrt[3]{2} + (b^2 - ac) \sqrt[3]{4})$$

Of course, this method works quite generally. For example, for $x=a + b \sqrt[3]{p} + c \sqrt[3]{p}^2$ we have:

$$x^{-1} = \frac{1}{a^3 - 3pabc + pb^3 + p^2 c^3} \cdot ((a^2 - pbc) + (pc^2 - ab) \sqrt[3]{p} + (b^2 - ac) \sqrt[3]{p}^2)$$

Comment: This looks great,...except I'm confused with where you say "evaluate at 1" .  I'm assuming you just mean let $y=1=(1,0,0)^T$ in terms of vectors because the coefficients of the basis radicals is just the first column of $x^{-1}$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. One evaluates the linear map at $1$, which means that we multiply the matrix with the corresponding vector $(1,0,0)$ (which I would not write as $1$, by the way) and then take the corresponding ring element of the vector.

Comment: This was a great answer.  I understood everything very clearly.  I had the matrix and seeing the invertible matrix argument using Cramer's rule was very insightful.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Try these:
[Rationalizing the denominator 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/681873/)
[Deradicalization of denominators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838287/)

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to remove the two previous posts that contain the same information...

Comment: @Michael Burr \\ Didn't realize that I had inadvertently done two comments. I chucked them finally.

Answer (score -1):

Not a great method if you'd like larger matrices, but I used Maple to get:

$$
x=\frac{a^2-2bc}{a^3-6abc+2b^3+4c^3}\qquad y=-\frac{ab-2c^2}{a^3-6abc+2b^3+4c^3}\qquad z=-\frac{ac-b^2}{a^3-6abc+2b^3+4c^3}.
$$

I didn't check that I typed everything correctly, but it's not too bad.

Comment: You don't understand things by typing them into Maple.

Comment: I have mathematica and I was going to do that, but as Martin said, I wanted to see if there was a better way to solve the system instead of row reduction, which is terrible with three variables.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Of course this isn't the way to understand the problem, but it depends on the application of interest.  If one just needs the inverse formally for a specific case, it works.  The OP was worried about an ugly calculation, so I pointed out that the calculation isn't too bad.